# How to install PIL with ZIP, JPEG, etc. on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: python, png, python-imaging-library, ubuntu-11.10

I am trying to be able to import png, which I believe is from the PIL. I would also prefer if JPEG and the others were also working

I am running Ubuntu 11.10.

now from http://jj.isgeek.net/2011/09/install-pil-with-jpeg-support-on-ubuntu-oneiric-64bits/
i have figured a few things out.

I tried

```
$ sudo apt-get install libjpeg libjpeg-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev  
pip install PIL  
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib  
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib  
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib  
pip install -U PIL
```

where all of his/her JPEG, ZLIB, FREETYPE2 were supported mine said support
not installed

I also went to [How to install PIL in Ubuntu 11.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225514/how-to-install-pil-in-ubuntu-11-04) and I tried
    `sudo apt-get install python imaging` then going through all of the `setup.py and`selftest.py`, but still it wasn't working
I went on to try from [PIL encoder jpeg not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479344/pil-encoder-jpeg-not-available). I downloaded the source files from the pythonware.com and moved is to usr/lib using mv
then, per the stackoverflow instructions, i tried adding a line after line 213:

```
add_directory(library_dirs, "usr/lib")  
sudo python setupt.py install  
python selftest.py
```

but still JPEG, ZLIB, FREETYPE2 were 'support not installed, but now there was another line that said LITTLECMS support not installed.

please help me sort this out.

Comment: Creating symbolic links works fine for me on 12.10 over i686

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository versions are working fine on 11.10 for me.  Did you use:

`sudo apt-get install python-imaging`

Note the dash between python and imaging, where you have a space.  You shouldn't need to manually run `setup.py` or any of that bollocks unless you actually need to build from source for some reason.  PNG should work out of the box.

Comment: i tried sudo apt-get install python-imaging. Then i went into the interpreter and tried import png and it's saying ImportError:No module named png.

Comment: @Calvin Hill: import png? I believe you are confusing PIL and PyPNG

Comment: I was able to get import png working with PyPNG, thanks EwynnTomato.

Comment: @EwyynTomato is correct .. python-imaging should let you `import Image`

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 12.04 I solved the issue helped by the "canonical" comment on http://effbot.org/zone/pil-decoder-jpeg-not-available.htm

1. Downloaded PIL manually
2. Modified JPEG_ROOT to point to the jpeg lib location: /usr/lib or /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu on x86 and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu on x64
3. Cleaned project (if it was already built) with python setup.py clean --all
4. On x86 and x64 I found that _imagingmath.so and _imaging.so where in the /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages directory AND also under /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL. I removed the first ones because they were loaded prior to the PIL distribution ones.
5. python setup.py build
6. python setup.py install

This was in the context of a Django/Mezzanine CMS usage.

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me, Ubuntu 14.04. I had to compile everything from source but I have to say it was the sweetest of all. No errors. Download from the following links and follow the various README's. Make sure that you are root as you execute instructions.
Download and install JPEG from http://www.ijg.org/.
Download and install PNG from http://www.zlib.net/.
Download and install Freetype from http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/.

Download and install PIL from http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/. In this last step, make sure as per the readme that you can see the ones that are installed correctly during

```
python setup.py build_ext -i
```

In some cases the following command might tell you something else but ignore it.
    python selftest.py

Cheers.
:-)